# How to add background rendering in FullCalendar 1.6

Tags: fullcalendar

In FullCalendar 2 i can add this code:

```
 events: [
    {
        start: '2014-11-10T10:00:00',
        end: '2014-11-10T16:00:00',
        rendering: 'background'
    }
```

and my events render in background with another color!
Is there a way to use this option with FullCalendar 1.6?

docs : http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/Background_Events/

Answer (score 1):

No easy way. If you wanted to change the background color of the whole day, you could just add the fc-highlight class to the appropriate column/row.

The only other way I see is making an actual event, then setting it as semi-transparent, no borders, low z-index, non-clickable and `cursor:default`.

A crazy option would be to backport the code for background events from the newer fullcalendar.